# How to say "I wish I could go back to those days?" in Spanish using subjunctive?

Tags: subjuntivo, tiempos-verbales

I am learning about the subjunctive mood in Spanish, and I want to say "I wish I could go back to those days".

Is

> Ojalá pueda volver a esos días.

correct?

Comment: Ojalá pudiera volver a esos días

Comment: Ojalá + pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo (eg. *pudiera* or *pudiese*) = action in the present that you'd wish to be true, even though it isn't. Ojalá + presente de subjuntivo (eg. *pueda*) = action in the future that may or may not occur. Compare *Ojalá vengan* ( they may come or not, but I hope they will) and *Ojalá vinieran* (I wish they would come, but they won't).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The present subjunctive of the verb "poder" in Spanish in the first person is ["pueda"](https://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-spanish-verb-poder.html) as you say in your translation, however a more accurate way of expressing the same wish in Spanish would be using the past subjunctive, which is counterfactual (it is actually impossible to go back to the past):

> Ojalá **pudiera** volver a esos días

or

> **Desearía** poder volver a esos días

I would think that your attempt of *Ojalá pueda volver a esos días* would be a better translation for

> I hope<sub><strike>wish</strike></sub> I can go back to those days

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gustavson for the edit.

Comment: Just to mention that the form "pudiese" is an alternative to "pudiera": they have the exact same meaning, but the former _may_ feel _slightly_ more formal.
Also note that while the second example retains the same meaning, "desearía" is not technically a subjuntive.
Also, +1 for the "ojalá"! =)